# Interface that declares an object type

Tags: c#, interface

This may be a question about fundamental design.

I want to perform an operation on a mystery object, as long as it implements my interface IMyInterface. And I want one of methods defined by the interace to return an instance of mystery object so...

```
IMyInterface
  {
    object GetInstance();
  }

public class MysteryObject : IMYInterface
}
  public object GetInstance()
    {
      MysteryObject instance = new MysteryObject();
      return instance;
    }
}
```

but this results in unnecessary 'object' types and the overhead associated with those.  C# specifically kills this overhead with the use of generic types.  It would be ideal to do something like this:

```
IMyInterface
  {
    T GetInstance<T>();
  }

public class MysteryObject : IMYInterface
}
  public MysteryObject GetInstance<MysteryObject>()
    {
      MysteryObject instance = new MysteryObject();
      return instance;
    }
}
```

I know this second example doesn't work. I know the syntax is wrong. ..but I'm wondering if there is a better way to require that an object that implements IMyInterface return an instance of it's own type.

My examples a little weird but i think most will understand the sentiment.  Strangely, I've found very little examples or questions around this.

Comment: there is almost no overhead for casting reference types to object back and forth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just make the return type `IMyInterface`:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    IMyInterface GetInstance();
}

public class MysteryObject : IMyInterface
{
    public IMyInterface GetInstance()
    {
        MysteryObject instance = new MysteryObject();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Or with generics:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T>
{
    T GetInstance();
}

public class MysteryObject : IMyInterface<MysteryObject>
{
    public MysteryObject GetInstance()
    {
        MysteryObject instance = new MysteryObject();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

If you want the generic argument to be of type IMyInterface you add constraint like this:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T>
    where T : IMyInterface<T>
{
    T GetInstance();
}
```

**Update**

Here are some example usages to see what the difference between these 2 versions is:

1. Returning interface `IMyInterface`:

   ```
   IMyInterface a = new MysteryObject().GetInstance(); // valid 
   MysteryObject b = new MysteryObject().GetInstance();// invalid 
   MysteryObject b = (MysteryObject)new MysteryObject().GetInstance(); // valid
   ```
2. Returning the generic type argument from the interface:

   ```
   IMyInterface<MysteryObject> a = new MysteryObject().GetInstance(); //valid
   MysteryObject b = new MysteryObject().GetInstance(); //valid
   ```

Comment: Comprehensive. Great answer. Is there a particular difference in cost between between returning the IMyInterface or the Generic?

Comment: With the generic version it will be directly converted to the specified generic type argument. If you're returning the interface you would have to cast it manually to convert it to `MysteryObject` for example.

Comment: @JamieMarshall I included examples in the answer.

Comment: thank you.  Last pick - i'm experimenting and it looks like I can return the type of the class that impliments IMyInterface, but what about returning an instance of a nested class within MysteryObject.  Is that just against the laws of nature?

Comment: @JamieMarshall Where you declare the class is of no difference, the class must inherit the requested by the constraint interface namely `IMyInterface<T>` of course if you exclude `where T : IMyInterface<T>` any class would fit the spot.

Answer (score 2):

You *almost* have it. You need to make the whole interface generic:

```
IMyInterface<T>
  {
    T GetInstance();
  }

public class MysteryObject : IMYInterface<MysteryObject>
}
  public MysteryObject GetInstance()
    {
      MysteryObject instance = new MysteryObject();
      return instance;
    }
}
```